# How can I have a dynamic property in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a method that allows me to print a message in the console and to be able to change the color of the message in that same method.

I send 2 parameters to carry out this action, `message` (which is the message that is printed in the console) and `color` (which is the color that I want to be printed in the console)

I have my code like this:

```
    public void Write(string message, string color = "White"){
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

But I need `ConsoleColor.White` to grab my dynamic color as follows (similar to javascript): `ConsoleColor [color]`;

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.
What I tried was the above: `ConsoleColor[color];`

Comment: Rather than accepting a string, why not accept a `ConsoleColor` instead? Does the color come from user input?

Comment: Why would you declare the `color` parameter as type `string` instead of type `ConsoleColor` in the first place?

Comment: If you need to convert a `String` to a `ConsoleColor` then, as with all enumerations, you can do so using the `Enum` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConsoleColor` is an Enum, so the usual way to do this would be to take a `ConsoleColor` as the second parameter:

```
public void Write(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White){
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

If you really need it to be a string, you can use `Enum.Parse`, but this runs the risk of a failed conversion if the caller passes an invalid color value:

```
public void Write(string message, string color = "White"){
    Console.ForegroundColor = Enum.Parse<ConsoleColor>(color);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Or if you want a version that won't throw with a bad value:

```
public void Write(string message, string color = "White"){
    Console.ForegroundColor = Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(color, out ConsoleColor parsedColor) 
                                            ? parsedColor : ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code helped me a lot and it is fully functional

Comment: You are better off putting in an extra line of code and using `Enum.TryParse`.  That way if someone enters `BeautifulRed`, you can sense the error (and, it has a generic version that takes the enum type)

Comment: Shouldn't you cast `Enum.Parse` result to `ConsoleColor`?

Comment: @Qwertyluk I think you're right.  Shows you how often I use this method.